# Integrate DocuSign with K2 workflow have an Object reference not set to an instance error

Tags: docusignapi

I am working on  Integrate DocuSign  with K2 workflow. But I get a Create Tab issue as below:

Service: DocuSign Service Guid: 262484e3-83d5-4222-ab93-599cf23c44ee Severity: Error Error Message: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Some documents can create tab successfuly some are not e.g. .docx files. My workflow as below:
[Click to see the Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nePOL.png)
[Click to see the Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y0uVo.png)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found out my answer from my research.
The answer as below :
1.On create Tab page we need to set the Lab property.
2. On create Tab page Positioning tag we need set the Anchor String property.
That is the answer thanks.